# Image tap event in ListView windows store app

Tags: c#, image, listview, windows-store-apps

I am developing my first application in windows 8 for WinRT. my application is implemented with one listview and listview contains two image control i want to add tap event on image control when image tapped then that image's visibility gets Collapsed and another image's visibility gets visible.
My code=

```
 <ListView Name="display" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <Image Source="{Binding  Path=Image}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Image_Name}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Gray" Margin="180,0,0,0"  />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Gray" Margin="140,0,0,0" />
               <Image x:Name="add" Source="{Binding  Path=Image1}" Height="30" Opacity="0.7" Tapped="add_Tapped" />
               <Image x:Name="sub" Source="{Binding  Path=Image2}" Height="30" Opacity="0.7" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I have used this code but it works for all the add image control not for particular item. i want to do it for only particular item which is pressed by user.

```
 private void SearchVisualTree(DependencyObject targetElement)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(targetElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return;
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(targetElement, i);
            if (child is Image)
            {
                Image myItems = (Image)child;
                if (myItems.Name == "add")
                {
                    myItems.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                   return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SearchVisualTree(child);
            }
        }
   }

    private void add_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchVisualTree(this.display);  //display is a listview name
     }
```

I want to create code for when add image tapped then add image's visibilty gets Collapsed and the another sub image's visibility gets visible for particular that item. how can I create it please help me. and another thing i am new to windows 8 development i want to use web api to this app with Json service. which tutorial can help me please suggest me.

Comment: please help me give me solution.

Comment: You mean, for example, if image named `add` tapped it should be collapsed and `sub` should become visible?

Comment: yes exactly both are in my listview