# xml parsing webapi to listview windows store apps c#

Tags: c#, listview, xml-parsing, windows-store-apps, asp.net-web-api

I am new to xml parsing i have used webapi xmlparsing with windows store app.
my xml coming from web is:

```
 <product>
  <id_products>1</id_products>   
   <images>
    <src isrenderimg="0" imagecodename="202">http://abcd.com/imagecache/abcjpg</src> 
   </images>
 </product>
 <product>
   <id_products>2</id_products> 
    <images>
      <src isrenderimg="0"imagecodename="203">http://abcd.com/imagecache/abc1.jpg</src> 
      <src isrenderimg="0" imagecodename="204">http://abcd.com/imagecache/abc2.jpg</src> 
    </images>
  </product>
```

I have 
parsed this xml with this code on Mainpage:

```
public class demo
  {
     public string Image { get; set; }
  }

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(apiurl of xml);
        var data = from query in xDoc.Descendants("images")
          select new demo
            {
              Image = query.Element("src").Value,
            };
        this.ListView1.DataContext = data;
    }`
```

my problem is that xml contains multiple src tags in images tag as show in upper xml code.
so my listview shows image only for first src tag not the others one i want to show all images of src tags which are in images tag in my listview how can it possible??please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please any one give me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to simply show all images from every `<src>` tag within `<images>`, you can try this way :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(apiurl of xml);
    var data = from query in xDoc.Descendants("images").Elements("src")
               select new demo
               {
                  Image = query.Value,
               };
    this.ListView1.DataContext = data;
}
```

Comment: thanks. please give me solution for this quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820812/image-tap-event-in-listview-windows-store-app