# Listview set default selected index of listview item windows store apps

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, windows-store-apps, listviewitem

My code contains the two listview. one is for category and second one is for data which is for selected item of first list. i want to set default selected index 0  of category list and second listview shows the data as selected index of first listview. both listviews are in my mainpage.xaml when my mainpage shows the category listview's index=0 is selected and another listview shows the data for selected category of first listview. bothe listview gets the data from internet. how can it possible
? please help me. code for first listview: `

```
<ListView x:Name="ctlist" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   SelectionChanged="ctlist_SelectionChanged"
SelectionMode="Single"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="1918" Height="80"   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource OrangeListViewItemStyle}" >   
     <ListView.ItemsPanel >
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stak3" Orientation="Horizontal" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  Margin="10,20,10,10" FontSize="25" Foreground="Black"   />
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>`
```

for second listview:

```
<ListView Name="display" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="None"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel x:Name="stak2" Orientation="Horizontal" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                  <Image Source="{Binding  Path=Image}" Width="500" Height="400"     />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Image_code}" FontSize="25" 
                       Foreground="Gray"      Margin="180,0,0,0"  />
                   <Image x:Name="add" Source="/Assets/new copy.png" Height="40" Opacity="0.7"               
                        Tapped="add_Tapped"  />  
             </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

App.xaml.cs contains

```
public ctlist selectedct { get; set; }
```

code:

```
 ctlist ctlistid;
      private void ctlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var app = App.Current as App;
            app.selectedct = (ctlist)ctlist.SelectedItem;
            ctlistid = app.selectedct;
            string no = ctlistid.Id.ToString();
            displayurl(no); // method for binding data to listview

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well you want to set the SelectedItemIndex of Category List view to 0 and also bind the data for the second ListView showing the data for that (Selected) Category.

You can do this as follows :

In the LoadState event after you set the DataSource for  ctlist set the selected index manually and then call the Selection Changed event . As shown below :

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {

        //TODO Set / Bind the data for Category List
        // do the binding here

        //Set the Selected Index
        ctlist.SelectedIndex = 0;

        //Manually call the selection changed event to set the data for the Categroy List
        ctlist_SelectionChanged(null, null);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. can you give me solution for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820812/image-tap-event-in-listview-windows-store-app

Answer (score 0):

I founded my answer of this question simply assign this keyword to set the default selected item after providing data source to ctlist listbox.

```
   private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
          {
            //TODO Set / Bind the data for Category List
             ctlist.ItemsSource = lst;

              this.ctlist.SelectedIndex = 0; 
          }
```